# SQL2008 MultiServerQuery

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How i will write multiserver Query in SQL2008?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a good blog entry that helps me very much:

http://blogs.msdn.com/sqlrem/archive/2008/02/04/multiple-server-query-execution-in-sql-server-2008.aspx